# Allow users to create and store data and retrieve it on login

Tags: user-meta, user-access

I write a wedding blog and would like to allow the subscribers to login and be able to create and save their own wedding guest lists. The data they store, should be retrievable on future login to the site.

I would like to know if this functionality would be possible and how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

you can store user data in user meta fields which you can get and display to the user.
use [update_user_meta();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) function to store user data and use [get_user_meta();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) to retrieve stored user data.

```
// you need to get user id and replace meta_key with yours
$user_data = 'some user lists data';
update_user_meta($user_id, 'meta_key', $user_data);

// now get user data
$stored_user_data = get_user_meta($user_id, 'meta_key', true);
```

Comment: Thanks, however I do not know coding, where do I need to place this piece of code to enable this functionality?